# Can I map a shortcut to move to the previous workspace?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, workspaces

Is there a way to map a shortcut to go to the previously visited workspace?

Comment: version of ubuntu? Please [edit] your question accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### For Ubuntu versions up to 21.10 (GNOME 40)

You can use the [Go To Last Workspace](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1089/go-to-last-workspace/) extension. Just install it and you should be able to use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to switch between the last two workspaces you used.

You may also want to read this: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)

---

#### For Ubuntu 22.04 (GNOME 42)

The extension isn't updated (yet?) to support Ubuntu 22.04 (GNOME 42). It can be made to work, though, by following these steps:

1. Go to the [extension's GitHub page](https://github.com/arjan/gnome-shell-go-to-last-workspace) and download it as zip (click [here](https://github.com/arjan/gnome-shell-go-to-last-workspace/archive/refs/heads/master.zip) to directly download the zip).
2. Open the location where you downloaded the zip and extract it.
3. Open the `metadata.json` file inside the extracted directory and change the line:

   ```json
   "version": 7,
   ```

   to:

   ```json
   "version": 8,
   ```

   Also change the line:

   ```json
   "shell-version": ["40", "3.38", "3.36", "3.34", "3.32", "3.30", "3.28"],
   ```

   to:

   ```json
   "shell-version": ["42", "40", "3.38", "3.36", "3.34", "3.32", "3.30", "3.28"],
   ```

   We just added support for GNOME 42. ;)
4. Now copy the extracted directory to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and change its name to `gnome-shell-go-to-last-workspace@github.com`.
5. Run the following command to set the keyboard shortcut to switch between workspaces.

   ```
   gsettings --schemadir ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/gnome-shell-go-to-last-workspace@github.com/schemas set org.gnome.shell.extensions.go-to-last-workspace shortcut-key "['<Super>escape']"
   ```

   In the above I'm using the default <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> shortcut, but you may adjust the above command for the shortcut of your choice.
6. Now restart GNOME Shell by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, entering `r` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> (works on Xorg only), or log out and log back in (works on both Xorg and Wayland).
7. The extension should now be enabled and you should be able to use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to switch between the last two visited workspaces.

   You may also want to install the Extension Manager so you can easily enable/disable extensions using the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
   ```

Comment: Thanks it works but how can i map it to Alt+Tab it doesn't allow me to set it trough the extension manager.

Comment: @Jerico I guess you first have to unassign the `Alt`+`Tab` shortcut by going to Settings > *Keyboard* > *Kyeboard Shortcuts*. Then search for *Switch windows*, click the shortcut and press `Backspace`. Then try the command in the answer to set the shortcut you wish.